# Built-in DNS server for Sonic wall?

Tags: domain-name-system, internal-dns, sonicwall, dnsmasq

I've got a Sonicwall TZ 215 that is currently being used as a firewall and DHCP server. Is there any built-in DNS server on this device I can use to map internal site names to IP addresses? I had this when I used DD-WRT in the form of DNSMasq.

Comment: Have you called Sonicwall and asked them?

Comment: I've spent a considerable amount of time searching for the answer online. I figured asking here would be quicker than dealing with phone support and allow others to see the answer as well.

Comment: I'm telling you that most of the folks here don't deal in Sonicwall products that small.  There may be one or two, but either way this is a question for the vendor and would probably take less time than you think to clarify.

Comment: You bought paid support... right?! :) Either way why do you want to run DNS there instead of from your ISP or another local internal box.

Comment: I have a few internal  .local domains that I'd like to point to a dev server, it doesn't seem worthwhile to run a whole DNS box to handle that.  Not sure if the firewall came with support. I'll definitely find out though.

Comment: You don't need a "whole DNS box." You just need a DNS service running on, e.g., your dev server.

Comment: That's what I've ended up doing for now. I'd rather just have that service on the Sonicwall though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[No, there is not.  It comes with DDNS, but not a proper DNS server.](http://www.sonicwall.com/downloads/TZ215_Series_DS_US.pdf)

> Dynamic DNS providers include: dyndns.org, yi.org, no-ip.com and changeip.com

(Ick.)